# Why do we divide by 2 getContentSize?

Tags: cocos2d-x

In [sample from Cocos2d-x Tutorials](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_3_-_How_to_Move_a_sprite) when we describe actionMove

```
CCFiniteTimeAction* actionMove = 
CCMoveTo::create( (float)actualDuration, 
ccp(0 - target->getContentSize().width/2, actualY) );
```

we set a point ccp(0 - target->getContentSize().width/2, actualY). If we have target with 20 width then we have point (-10, actualY), and half target must be visible, but it's not so. Why?

Initial target position

```
target->setPosition( 
  ccp(winSize.width + (target->getContentSize().width/2), 
  actualY) );
```

Here we also divide by 2, but I understand it (winSize.width + any number and target becomes invisible, outside the screen).

Comment: The target's intinal position is waht?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2d-x uses the center of the object as the origin/anchor point, rather than the corner.  So if you want half of your object to be visible on the edge of the screen, use:

```
ccp(0, actualY)
```

or

```
ccp(winSize.width)
```

You add half of the contentSize if you want the object to be completely off the screen.